# autocompletion on a list in jquery ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, autocomplete

I have a list in my html code in which there are 6-7 items in that list.There is a search box at top of the list,so when a user types alphabet A ,list should display only those items which contain A on start or inside the item name.

So lets say I am having 6 items in the list,two items containing A.And in the search box i Type 'a',then instead of 6 items getting displayed only two should be display and simultaneously for others,same as autocompletion on search box work

My code is below

```
 <ul>
<input type="text" name="search" placeholder="search">
    <li><a href="#" name="one">john</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" name="one">khair</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" name="one">compton</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" name="one">Jordan</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" name="one">Micheal</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" name="six">Peter</a></li>
    </ul>
```

Please help me with search box code

Comment: Are you using any jquery plugin for autocomplete currently ?

Comment: no,i m not using any plugin for autocomplete

Comment: Then you should consider using one ! If you want I can create a basic working JSFIDDLE for you !

Comment: ya.plz.bcoz i tried making the code.but no success

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try Like

> HTML

```
<input type="text" id="query" class="text-field valid" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Search here">
```

> Javascript

```
a1 = $('#query').autocomplete({
width: 448,
delimiter: /(,|;)\s*/,
lookup: 'Andorra,Azerbaijan,Bahamas,Bahrain,Bangladesh,Barbados,Belarus,Belgium,Belize,Benin,Bhutan,Bolivia,Bosnia Herzegovina,Botswana,Brazil,Brunei,Bulgaria,Burkina, Burundi,Cambodia,Cameroon,Canada,Cape Verde,Central African Rep,Chad,Chile,China,Colombia,Comoros,Congo,Congo {Democratic Rep},Costa Rica,Croatia,Cuba,Cyprus,Czech Republic,Denmark,Djibouti,Dominica,Dominican Republic,East Timor,Ecuador,Egypt,El Salvador,Equatorial Guinea,Eritrea,Estonia,Ethiopia,Fiji,Finland,France,Gabon,Gambia,Georgia,Germany,Ghana,Greece,Grenada,Guatemala,Guinea,Guinea-Bissau,Guyana,Haiti,Honduras,Hungary,Iceland,India,Indonesia,Iran,Iraq,Ireland {Republic},Israel,Italy,Ivory Coast,Jamaica,Japan,Jordan,Kazakhstan,Kenya,Kiribati,Korea North,Korea South,Kosovo,Kuwait,Kyrgyzstan,Laos,Latvia,Lebanon,Lesotho,Liberia,Libya,Liechtenstein,Lithuania,Luxembourg,Macedonia,Madagascar,Malawi,Malaysia,Maldives,Mali,Malta,Marshall Islands,Mauritania,Mauritius,Mexico,Micronesia,Moldova,Monaco,Mongolia,Montenegro,Morocco,Mozambique,Myanmar, {Burma},Namibia,Nauru,Nepal,Netherlands,New Zealand,Nicaragua,Niger,Nigeria,Norway,Oman,Pakistan,Palau,Panama,Papua New Guinea,Paraguay,Peru,Philippines,Poland,Portugal,Qatar,Romania,Russian Federation,Rwanda,St Kitts & Nevis,St Lucia,Saint Vincent & the Grenadines,Samoa,San Marino,Sao Tome & Principe,Saudi Arabia,Senegal,Serbia,Seychelles,Sierra Leone,Singapore,Slovakia,Slovenia,Solomon Islands,Somalia,South Africa,South Sudan,Spain,Sri Lanka,Sudan,Suriname,Swaziland,Sweden,Switzerland,Syria,Taiwan,Tajikistan,Tanzania,Thailand,Togo,Tonga,Trinidad & Tobago,Tunisia,Turkey,Turkmenistan,Tuvalu,Uganda,Ukraine,United Arab Emirates,United Kingdom,United States,Uruguay,Uzbekistan,Vanuatu,Vatican City,Venezuela,Vietnam,Yemen,Zambia,Zimbabwe'.split(',')
});
```

OR

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        var availableTags = [
            "ActionScript",         "AppleScript",
            "Asp",              "BASIC",
            "C",                "C++",
            "Clojure",              "COBOL",
            "ColdFusion",           "Erlang",
            "Fortran",              "Groovy",
            "Haskell",              "Java",
            "JavaScript",           "Lisp",
            "Perl",             "PHP",
            "Python",               "Ruby",
            "Scala",                "Scheme"
        ];
        $( ".tags" ).autocomplete({
            source: availableTags
        });
    });
    </script>

<div><input class="tags" type="text" /></div>
<div><input class="tags" type="text" /></div>
```

OR

```
$('#tags').on('keyup',function(e){
  // cache all the tag elements in an array
  var tagElems = $('#autocompletes1').children();

  // hide all tags
  $(tagElems).hide();


  for(var i = 0; i < tagElems.length; i++){ // loop through all tagElements
    var tag = $(tagElems).eq(i);

    if(($(tag).text().toLowerCase()).indexOf($(this).val().toLowerCase()) === 0){
      // if element's text value starts with the hint show that tag element
      $(tag).show();
    }
  }
});
```

[Demo](http://jsbin.com/uROmiVi/1/edit)

[Demo2](http://jsfiddle.net/ashuslove/kLV3y/41/)

[Demo3](http://jsfiddle.net/ashuslove/9HjWQ/18/)

Comment: but.i want the list to show only those items which are having the entered text.not like autocompletion on search box only

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/phpdeveloperrahul/cS2bL/) **customized according to your needs**:

HTML code:

```
<div class="ui-widget">
<label for="tags">Search: </label>
<input id="tags">
</div>
```

JS code:

```
 $(function() {
var availableTags = [
"john",
"khair",
"compton",
"Jordan",
"Micheal",
"Peter"
];
$( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
source: availableTags
});
});
```

The plugin I have used is [jQuery-ui autocomplete](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/). You can refer its documentation and demo examples. This plugin is awesome and highly customizable !